# Tag synonym for Roman-Catholic

Tags: support

I am a bit short of the 1250 rep to create tag synonyms.  But I'm thinking that we should create the synonym between these two tags:

[roman-catholic](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman-catholic)

[catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism)

Could we (should we) synonymize those?

Comment: I agree, but do Catholicism (with an i)

Comment: @Peter Whoops, thanks.  Sometimes I type faster than I think.  (The tag is spelled correctly, though.  Just not my typing).

Comment: Do you know about the markdown syntax for tags?  You just put a square brackets around what you want to type, then inside type tag:catholicism.  It looks nice that way, and it links straight to the tag search page.

Comment: NICE!  That's handy.  I was wondering how others did that....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Merged. There is now only one, holy, catholic and apostolic tag, named "[catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism)". [roman-catholic](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman-catholic) and [catholic](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholic) are synonyms.